# Replacing an element into a list Scheme

Tags: list, scheme, racket

I need to replace an element from a list with another element in Scheme, but the problem is that the list where I need to replace can be nested.

For example, if I have the list `'(1 (2 3 4 5) (6 7))` and I need to replace 5 with 9, my output should be `'(1 (2 3 4 9) (6 7))`.

Can you please help me with this problem?

Comment: um what have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a basic strategy for solving this kind of problem:

1. First, solve it for a flat list. i.e., write the function so that it works if the input list has no sublists.
2. Then, add a condition so that if the element you're inspecting is a list, then recurse into your function with that list.

Here's some skeletal code:

```
(define (replace lst from to)
  (cond ((null? lst) '())                ;; end of input
        ((list? (car lst)) <???>)        ;; encountered a sublist
        ((equal? (car lst) from) <???>)  ;; found the element we're replacing
        (else <???>)))                   ;; everything else
```

Notice that the second `cond` clause, `(list? (car lst))`, is the only thing that's new in your sublist-capable version.

Comment: I have the function for a list without sublists. I don't know how to recurse into the function if (car lst) is a list.

Comment: Okay, that's easy. You know how you handled the case where you're matching the element you're replacing, right? Your answer should be of the form `(cons <???> (replace (cdr lst) from to))`. The answer for the sublist case is similar, just with a different expression for `<???>`.

Comment: (Hint: What if the inner list were a flat list? What would you use for `<???>`? Would it still work if it were not actually flat?)

Answer (score 2):

here is a function:

```
(define (replace L new old)
   (cond ;;((null? L) L)
         ((list? L)
          (map
              (lambda (lst) (replace lst new old))
              L))
         (else
              (if (equal? L old)
                   new
                   L))))
```

examples of use:

```
> (replace '(1 (1 2 3 4 (5 6 3) 3 4)) 7 3)
'(1 (1 2 7 4 (5 6 7) 7 4))

> (replace '() 7 3)
'()

> (replace '(1 (1 2 3 4) 3 4) 7 3)
'(1 (1 2 7 4) 7 4)
```

or:

```
(define (replace L new old)

  (if (list? L)
      (map
       (lambda (lst) (replace lst new old))
       L)
      (if (equal? L old)
      new
      L)))
```

example:

(replace '(1 (1 2 3 4 (5 6 3) 3 4)) 7 3) ->  '(1 (1 2 7 4 (5 6 7) 7 4))